# How to compile with boost/python numpy library? Make can't find the library files

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost, makefile

I have a C++ extension that uses the numpy library from Boost/Python. Here's the .h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <utility>
#include <deque>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>


#include <python3.6m/Python.h>
#include <boost169/boost/python/object/pickle_support.hpp>
#include <boost169/boost/python/dict.hpp>
#include <boost169/boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost169/boost/python/numpy.hpp>

class MyClass : public Node{
public:
    // attributes
    // functions
}
```

the Makefile:

```
myclass.o:myclass.cpp node.cpp address.cpp foo.cpp info.cpp container.cpp
    g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m myclass.cpp node.cpp address.cpp foo.cpp info.cpp container.cpp -c -lpython3.6m -lboost_numpy36 -lboost_python3


MyClass.so:myclass.o node.o address.o foo.o info.o container.o
    g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -L /lib64 -shared myclass.o node.o address.o foo.o info.o container.o -o MyClass.so -lpython3.6m -lboost_numpy36 -lboost_python3
```

And the usr/lib64 folder contains the following files:

```
locate boost_numpy
/usr/lib64/libboost_numpy27.so.1.69.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_numpy36.so.1.69.0
/usr/lib64/boost169/libboost_numpy27.so
/usr/lib64/boost169/libboost_numpy36.so
```

However when I try to compile, it gives me an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_numpy36
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MyClass.so] Error 1
```

It gave me the same results with the different names:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost169/boost_numpy36
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MyClass.so] Error 1

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_numpy36.so.1.69.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MyClass.so] Error 1
```

Is there something I'm missing? Both boost_python3 and python3.6m are have a .so file in the lib64 directory and they compile just fine

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this behind `-L /lib64` and it worked:
`-L /lib64/boost169`